# How to partially change condition value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with updown and step columns.

If the value of the updown column is "DOWN" I want to add "-" before the value of the step column.

The current state is

```
df["updown"][0] = "DOWN"
df["step"][0] = "18"
```

after

```
df["updown"][0] = "DOWN"
df["step"][0] = "-18"
```

Is there any way? I tried this method but it failed

```
df.loc[df["updown"]=="DOWN"] = df["step"].apply(lambda x: "-" + x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1['step']=np.where(df1['updown'].str.contains(r'\DOWN\b'),'-'+df1['step'],df1['step'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the selection on both sides of the assignment expression and you can save it as a variable to avoid code duplication:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'updown': ['DOWN', 'UP'], 'step': ['18', '8']})
mask = df.updown == 'DOWN'
df.loc[mask, 'step'] = '-' + df.loc[mask, 'step']
print(df['step'][0]) # '-18'
```

Although it seems strange that the `step` value is a string instead of an int. It it were a number, you could simply do:

```py
df.loc[mask, 'step'] *= -1
```